# Display android notifications having image

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

i am working with android app using java.I want to show notification with large image when app is in background or killed

Comment: then you probably need to run a foreground service with a custom notification

Answer (score 1):

You should use data payload for displaying notifications when the app is in the background. Send the image url as data and download it on your mobile before displaying . Some thing like this:

```
public void showImageNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
  if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
  Map<String, String> messageData = remoteMessage.getData();
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentText(messageData.get("text"))
            .setContentTitle(messageData.get("title"))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.localplay_logo_notification)
            .setColorized(true)    
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (messageData.containsKey("image")) {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(messageData.get("image"));
        if (bitmap != null) {
            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap));
        }
    }
   notificationManager.notify(121, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```